# Install multiple .net versions in Windows Containers

Tags: .net, docker

I would like to have container that has .netcore3.1 and Net6.0 installed (There are multiple exe's that needs ot be executed inside the container which uses diff framework)

For Linux based container I had the following Docker File.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
COPY --from=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 /usr/share/dotnet /usr/share/dotnet
```

After creating the image on typing the belwo command, I get into the container with the below command.

> docker run -it  {Imgname}

On typing **dotnet --list-sdks** I could see both the versions installed.

Now I am trying to do the samething for windows container.

am not sure how to install in Windows container.

Could someone plz guide me how to install both hte SDK's in the **Windows Container** as the COPY statement is wokring.

Thanks.